# MySQL: Select nth rows where at least one has a attribute set?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, having

I’ve a table in MySQL called **words**.

One column is called **word** (the actually word) and the other is called **special**

I’ve a query I’m trying to perform which - if possible - should do this:

`SELECT word FROM words WHERE special = 1 AT LEAST ONCE`

This is of cause a pseudo-like query but the thing I want is to get randomly nth records from my words table where AT LEAST ONE of the words has the attribute **special** set to 1.

It means that all nth records is allowed to be 1 if this is the case or all but one of the nth records can have **special** = 0 but there have to be at least one which has the **special** = 1.

I’ve tried something like:
`SELECT * FROM words HAVING COUNT(isNum = 1) > 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` or something like this.. It does not give me the result I want back, actually it only returns one result.

Can this be done by SQL??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that should be relatively efficient, sort of.  It selects one random "special" word, then n + 1 other words (which might contain the first word).  It orders them so the random one is guaranteed to be first, and then select n of them.

```
select word
from ((select word, 0 as ordering
       from words
       where special = 1
       order by rand()
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select word, rand() as ordering
       from words
       limit n
      )
     ) t
group by word
order by min(ordering)
limit n;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer. It works, sort of, but it seems to  always only select maximum one record with special = 1 and not 1> records. But it is as close as I've got myself, so it will do :-)

Comment: @Mestika . . . There is no reason why it wouldn't select more than one.  Increase n to a large number and you will probably see additional ones.  It all depends on the proportion that are special, the total number of rows, and the value of `n`.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. It works perfectly :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM words
HAVING COUNT(special = 1) > 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Using `COUNT()` here without `GROUP` simply counts the number of records and returns 1 row, then applies the `HAVING` clause to that one row, yielding one record in your result set.

If you add `COUNT()` to the `SELECT` clause, you'll kind of see your mistake:

```
SELECT COUNT(special = 1), words.*
FROM words
HAVING COUNT(special = 1) > 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

The record that it returns after the count is indeterminate.

So, you must add `GROUP BY` to get multiple records back (one per word):

```
SELECT *
FROM words
GROUP BY word
HAVING COUNT(special = 1) > 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Now, you'll notice that it returns all words with more than one record, regardless of whether it has `special = 1`.

That's because `special = 1` is a Boolean expression that returns `0` or `1`. `COUNT()` increments on both `COUNT(0)` and `COUNT(1)`. Actually, it increments on anything but `COUNT(NULL)`. Now, you realize that you really want `SUM()`.

```
SELECT *
FROM words
GROUP BY word
HAVING SUM(special = 1) > 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more straight-forward:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM words
WHERE special = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcus and thanks for giving me the walkthrough of my error in my own query. I suspected that it wasn't as easy as I thought to do so.   
What actually worked for me was your third query. The last query did only select words where special = 1 and I wanted to select between both special = 0 and special = 1.